# How to update data from DataGridViewTable in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to update the data in datagridviewtable, but there is the error at cmd.CommandText. How to fixed it?

```
private void btnUPDATE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

    if (textBox3.Text != ""&textBox1.Text != ""&textBox2.Text != ""&comboBox1.Text != "")
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "update LoginDb set  ID='" + textBox3.Text + "',NAME='" + textBox1.Text + "',PASSWORD='" + textBox2.Text + "',STATUS='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
         MessageBox.Show("UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY!!!!!!!");

        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex=-1;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I also notice, there is no `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Are you trying to UPDATE an existing record or INSERT a new record into the LoginDb table?  Also, just judging by the name should your SQL insert a number instead of a string into the ID column (ie. "Update LoginDb set ID=" + textBox3.Text + ", NAME='"...)?  If you want to do an UPDATE, then you'll probably need to specify which record to update in a WHERE clause.  Also, I'm assuming your error was not a compiler error but a runtime error, correct?  What's the error?